# Will cookies change if user agent changes

Tags: cookies

i m using php simple html dom to fetch some data from some sites. on my code, i use random different user agent when making a connection. Does the cookies get changed every time when my bot change the user agent?

Comment: It probably depends on a few factor, but I wouldn't count on this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

No. User agent is a seperate header to a cookie.

If you are programatically calling web pages the library/framework would need to keep track if the cookies, otherwuse it will generate a new one each time.

Of-course, your IP will not change unless you do something on the network...